Derivation of Equation of Motion of Graviton
In Feynman's Lectures on Graviton, Feynman tries to simplify the equation of motion of gravitation field,
$$h_{\alpha\beta,\sigma}^{,\sigma} - (h_{\alpha\sigma,\beta}^{,\sigma} + h_{\beta\sigma,\alpha}^{,\sigma})$$
$$ +( h_{\sigma,\alpha\beta}^{\sigma}+ \eta_{\alpha\beta}h^{\sigma\rho}_{,\sigma\rho}) $$
$$-\eta_{\alpha\beta}h^{\sigma,\mu}_{\sigma,\mu}$$
$$=-\lambda T_{\alpha\beta}\tag{3.6.2}$$
with simplified symbol
$ \bar{h}^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}(x^{\mu\nu} + x^{\nu\mu}) - \frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}x^{\sigma}_{\sigma}\tag{3.7.1}$
Then the field equation can be written in a symmetrized form,
$$h_{\mu\nu\,\sigma}^{\sigma} - 2\bar{h}_{\mu\sigma,\nu}^{,\sigma} = -\lambda\bar{T}\_{\mu\nu}\tag{3.7.4}$$
When I tried to derive the simplified equation, I find something wrong. I have
$$2(h\_{,\mu\nu}^{\mu\nu} - h^{\sigma,\rho}\_{\sigma,\rho}) = -\lambda T^{\sigma}\_{\sigma}$$
which would cancel the last two terms in eq(3.6.2), however, I'm not sure how $\bar{h}\_{\mu\sigma,\nu}^{,\sigma}$ would cancel the second and third term in eq(3.6.2).
$$\bar{h}\_{\mu\sigma,\nu}^{,\sigma} = \left(h_{\mu\sigma}-\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\sigma}h^{\rho}_{\rho}\right)\_{,\nu}^{,\sigma}$$
I think the problem may be the definition of bar symbol used by Feynman, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
